# How to make a flutter view take the full width and height of the layout?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm working on an application where I add flutter to my application developed in Android Studio.

Specifically, I have a button that allows me to pass from android to flutter, but when the flutter view opens it does not take all the full size of the android layout.

Does anyone know how I can make the flutter view take the full size of the layout on android?

[image: Android layout]

This is the code that I already have:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_flutter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_flutter = findViewById(R.id.btn_flutter);
    btn_flutter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View flutterview = Flutter.createView(MainActivity.this,getLifecycle(),"r1");

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams framelayout =  new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            addContentView(flutterview, framelayout);
        }
    });

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_flutter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Flutter"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="341dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show your activity_main.xml?

Comment: In the layout I only have the button with the Id as "@+id/ btn_flutter"

Comment: are you sure there is no padding in parent layout in activity_main.xml?

Comment: No, I don't have any padding in the layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Flutter using `Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;`
Try making your Flutter Widget as follow:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```